# Python, Insert HTML table to email body (not attached)

Tags: python, email

I'm looking for a way to insert an html table into emails body (not attached / not hyperlinked).

What i did so far, and it is not good enough is:

1: Attach the table as a file to mail.

2: Convert html to csv and paste to email body.

3: Added a hyperlink to mail with link to table.

Tried with Mailer and email.MIMEMultipart

I guess i am missing something, it seems so trivial.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Python email documentation - 18.1.11. email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id4):

> Here’s an example of how to create an HTML message with an alternative
>   plain text version:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: So i had a problem in my html table, so it was not attached to mail....thanks